# Multiple Custom Lookup in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a custom generic lookup component, which I have created from here https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc#about

I have used this component for two lookups in the same parent component, one for custom object and another for picklist values.

The custom object search is working fine but the picklist values search is not working.

I guess it's because of the way how selected values are added.
How do I set values to correct lookup and how do get correct values from lookup.

HTML:

```
<c-lookup
                selection={assignedToInitialSelection}
                errors={errors}
                onsearch={handleSearch}
                onselectionchange={handleSelectionChange}
                label="Attendees"
                placeholder="Search Salesforce"
                data-id="contactTo"
                is-multi-entry={isMultiEntryAssignedTo}></c-lookup>
                    
        <c-lookup
                selection={picklistSelection}
                errors={picklistErrors}
                onsearch={handlePicklistSearch}
                onselectionchange={handlePicklistChange}
                label="Related to Picklist"
                placeholder="Search Salesforce"
                data-id="relatedPicklist"
                is-multi-entry={isMultiEntryAssignedTo}></c-lookup>
```

JS:

```
 handleSearch(event) {
        contactSearch(event.detail)
            .then(results => {
                this.template
                    .querySelector('c-lookup')
                    .setSearchResults(results);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Lookup error', JSON.stringify(error));
                this.errors = [error];
            });
    }
    
    handlePicklistSearch(event) {
        getPicklistName(event.detail)
            .then(results => {
                this.template
                    .querySelector('c-lookup')
                    .setSearchResults(results);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.error('Lookup error', JSON.stringify(error));
                this.relatedFundsErrors = [error];
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.template.querySelector('c-lookup')` method returns the first component of type `c-lookup` found in the DOM.

So in your `handlePicklistSearch` method, the lookup returned is the "Attendees" one.

You should add ids to your lookups to be able to query the one you want.

For example :

```
    <c-lookup
            data-id="attendees"
            selection={assignedToInitialSelection}
            errors={errors}
            onsearch={handleSearch}
            onselectionchange={handleSelectionChange}
            label="Attendees"
            placeholder="Search Salesforce"
            data-id="contactTo"
            is-multi-entry={isMultiEntryAssignedTo}></c-lookup>
                
    <c-lookup
            data-id="related"
            selection={picklistSelection}
            errors={picklistErrors}
            onsearch={handlePicklistSearch}
            onselectionchange={handlePicklistChange}
            label="Related to Picklist"
            placeholder="Search Salesforce"
            data-id="relatedPicklist"
            is-multi-entry={isMultiEntryAssignedTo}></c-lookup>
```

JS :

```
handleSearch(event) {
    contactSearch(event.detail)
        .then(results => {
            this.template
                .querySelector('[data-id="attendees"]')
                .setSearchResults(results);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Lookup error', JSON.stringify(error));
            this.errors = [error];
        });
}

handlePicklistSearch(event) {
    getPicklistName(event.detail)
        .then(results => {
            this.template
                .querySelector('[data-id="related"]')
                .setSearchResults(results);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.error('Lookup error', JSON.stringify(error));
            this.relatedFundsErrors = [error];
        });
}
```